# Removing non App Store apps

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, dmg

I use several apps installed using `.dmg` files downloaded from other sources rather than direct from the App Store.

When I try to remove them through Launchpad, these apps will not show the **X** button to allow me to delete them.

[image]
<sup>On the right: Mac App Store app; On the left: app from external source.</sup>

Is there any canonical safety way to remove them?

If I put them in Trash, will they disappear from my Mac without any related directories? How can I completely remove an app?

Answer (score 2):

To remove just the app you can drag it to the trash, use <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⌫ backspace</kbd>, or right-click → **Move to Trash** the app.

To remove the app, its preference files, and other related files, you will need another app along the lines of the free [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) application.

Here is a Lifehacker article titled "[The Best App Uninstaller for Mac](http://lifehacker.com/5828738/the-best-app-uninstaller-for-mac)", which chose [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) as the best uninstaller for the Mac (in 2011).

Answer (score 1):

> There isn't an app out there which really deletes all of the files
>   related to a certain app. To be completely sure, you have to do it by
>   hand.

1. Open up the Terminal
2. Type in `sudo find / -iname "*YOURAPPNAME*" -print > ~/Desktop/uninstall.txt`
3. Open the uninstall.txt file at your Desktop and look at the content
4. Now go through, line by line, and when you are sure a path is related to your app, type this on the command line (*the path is just an example here*):
5. `sudo rm -r "~/Library/Application\ Support/APPNAME"`

**Many apps don't look deep enough, or in favor of security, don't delete all files they find.**