# How to Uninstall Office for Mac 2016

Tags: ms-office

How can I COMPLETELY uninstall Microsoft Office for Mac 2016

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing non App Store apps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103476/removing-non-app-store-apps)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [the most obvious link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-for-Mac-eefa1199-5b58-43af-8a3d-b73dc1a8cae3)?

Tested and I can confirm that it works.